# How to fill Treeview Fill from database

Tags: wpf, treeview

I want to use tree-view as a main menu.
I want to Fill the treeview in WPF and MVVM that table has the path like abc.xaml and when user click that page/window will be open

if there are any mistake then ignore please I am new one

Comment: you can do it, what is the problem

Comment: how me fill tree view and open page or window

Comment: no one will write application for you here, try to do it, and ask if you have any issues

Comment: I only want if there are any example then give me that link etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is to create viewmodel for nodes, and use [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx) for creating view

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx) sample is exactly what you are looking for

```
<Window x:Class="SDKSample.Window1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="HierarchicalDataTemplate Sample"
  xmlns:src="clr-namespace:SDKSample">
  <DockPanel>
    <DockPanel.Resources>
      <src:ListLeagueList x:Key="MyList"/>

      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType    = "{x:Type src:League}"
                                ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Divisions}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType    = "{x:Type src:Division}"
                                ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Teams}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Team}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </DockPanel.Resources>

    <Menu Name="menu1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <MenuItem Header="My Soccer Leagues"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyList}}" />
    </Menu>

    <TreeView>
      <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyList}}" Header="My Soccer Leagues" />
    </TreeView>

  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```